# Fourier transform of the n-th derivative (without induction)

Tags: fourier-transform

Is there a direct way to get $\widehat{f^{(n)}}(\omega)=(i \omega)^{n} \hat{f}(\omega)$ without induction on $n$ ?

I tried to use integration by parts for $$\mathcal{F}\{ f_n(x) \}=\widehat{f^{(n)}}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(x) e^{-i \omega x} dx,$$
with $u=e^{-i \omega x}$ and $v=f^{(n+1)}(x)/{(n+1)}.$
Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Gievn that the $n$-th derivative is itself an inductively-constructed concept, I doubt that.

Comment: @AlexM. thanks for the reply. I was wondering what if we don't know the formula, is there a way to get it directly. May be not.

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}f(x)&=\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\omega)\,\mathrm e^{i\omega x}\,\mathrm d\omega\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\omega)\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\,\left(\mathrm e^{i\omega x}\right)\,\mathrm d\omega\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty(i\omega)^n\hat f(\omega)\,\mathrm e^{i\omega x}\,\mathrm d\omega\\
&=\mathcal F^{-1}\{(i\omega)^n\hat f(\omega)\}
\end{align*}
$$
and then $\widehat{f^{(n)}}(\omega)=(i \omega)^{n} \hat{f}(\omega)$