# A contradiction? Inconsistent expression of Hermite functions as eigenvalues of Fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-analysis, eigenfunctions, hermite-polynomials

For a funcion $\phi\in L_2$ let $\widehat{\phi}$ denote its Fourier transform. Denote the $n$-th Hermite function by $\phi_n$. We know three things:

1) By [Fourier transform of the n-th derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1939977/622884),
$$\widehat{\frac{d^n\phi}{dx^n}}(w) = (iw)^n\widehat{f}(w)$$

2) By definition, $$\phi_n = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{x^2}$$

3) [Hermite functions are eigenvectors of the Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions_as_eigenfunctions_of_the_Fourier_transform), specifically
$$\widehat{\phi_n} = (-i)^n \phi_n.$$

But therefore [using 3) 2) 1) and 2) in order]
$$(-i)^n \phi_n(x) = \widehat{\phi_n}(x) = \widehat{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{x^2}} = (ix)^ne^{x^2} = (ix)^n\phi_0$$ 
[with a normalization constant ommited in the fourth term] and thus
$$(-1)^n\phi_n(x) = x^n\phi_0(x)$$
which is clearly a contradiction, because of 2) for $n\geq 1.$

Do you have any idea of where is the error in my reasoning? is this an inconsistency in mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

[You mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions_as_eigenfunctions_of_the_Fourier_transform)  $$\phi_n(x) = e^{x^2/2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$$ they are eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform $f\to \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx$ (the constant factor is to make it unitary). The eigenvalue is automatically $\pm 1,\pm i$ because $\mathcal{F}^4 f=f$.

Comment: The first function you write $\phi_n$ is the definition of the Hermite polynomial. This is not an answer to the question, which is about finding the error I can not find.